# Python socket server and pipe

Tags: python, linux, sockets, pipe, python-2.x

I have three files. client.py, server.py and test.py. client.py is below:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 6088))
while True:
    a = raw_input()
    s.send(a)
s.close()
```

server.py:

```
import socket
import sys
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1',6088))
s.listen(1)
print("Waitting for connection.....")
while True:
    socket,addr = s.accept()
    while True:
        data = socket.recv(1024)
        if data:
           print(data)
s.close()
```

test.py:

```
while True:
    a = raw_input()
    print("welcom "+ a)
```

I use `server.py` or `test.py` to start the server, then I use the `client.py`to start the client, but when I am inputting something in client, the server doesn't show anything. Why? And how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried to use unbuffered output, i.e. `python -u server.py | ....` ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but can we assume you see the server printing messages if you don't pipe its output to the test script?

Comment: Also, I see there's an assumption that both scripts in the pipeline are running in parallel. Is this assumption true - or do piped commands on linux execute sequentially (python test.py won't get the stdout of server.py until it completes).

Comment: @Todd If i don't pipe its, I can see the messages.May be the problem is the i use the pipe in wrong way.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks it work! but why?

Comment: Ah.. so the piped scripts do run parallel!? So @FledgeXu, turning off buffering means that the server script's output goes immediately to test.py.  As opposed to buffered output which means server.py's output goes to fill up a buffer before the OS (or Python interp) decides to move the buffer contents to test.py.

Comment: @Todd It's should run in parallel, you can check out this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79501/executing-piped-commands-in-parallel).

Comment: @FledgeXu: see my answer for an explanation why `-u` helps.

Answer (score 3):

By default the output from Python is buffered for performance reasons unless stdout goes to a terminal. This means any output from `print` will not be send immediately to the pipe but will first be buffered inside the Python process and only send if enough data have accumulated in the buffer. To switch this off and make any output be send immediately to the pipe use `python -u` [or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering). 
Note that this behavior is not unique to Python. Other commands (like perl) show a similar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to turn off buffering completely (this could cause inefficiencies in other parts of the code), just call sys.stdout.flush() after each print statement in server.py.